# socket.io - how to make client wait for a response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Here is the scenario,

I have 2 nodes, let's call them node A and node B. I want node A to wait to continue executing the rest of the code until it gets a response from node B (not waiting for acknowledgment from node B that it receives the message from node A, but I need node A to wait until it receives data from node B). I think I have to use promise and async but can't seem to wrap my head around implementing it. Any suggestions for doing this?

### EDIT

NodeA.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    io.emit('triggerEvent', (response_from_B) => {
        console.log(response_from_B)
    });
});
```

NodeB.js

```
var socket = io_client.connect('url_A', {reconnect: true});
var data_from_B = 'some_date';
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.on('triggerEvent', (fn) => {

    // Some process with data_from_B

    fn(data_from_B);
    });
});
```

Please keep in mind that i am still getting familiar with socket.io. Node A and node B are two different application that are communicating with each other using socket.io. When a user access node A (application A), that data is then shared with node B (application B) by socket.io instantly. In that case, node A is acting like a server and node B is acting like the client. The opposite can also be true. The snippet that i shared is when a user is accessing node A, which will act like a server and send data to node B, which will act like a client. I need some help when node A trigger an `emit` and receive data from node B, which i am assuming using callback. When i try the code above, i get an error saying:

`Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting`

Any tips on how to do this? Or are there any suggestions on how to approach this differently?

Comment: Questions about code need to contain your actual code (not pseudo-code).  Please add the relevant code to your question and will be able to help you better. Theoretical questions are to hard to target your specific situation without writing several chapters of a book.  In general, you don't make node wait for anything.  Instead, you register an interest in some future event with an event handler or a promise or a callback and you go about the rest of the app's business.  Then, when the event, callback or promise triggers, you pick up where you left off - event driven architecture.

Comment: Not sure if that was the case back then, but there is `socket.call()` these days that blocks until an emitted has been consumed and the consumer returned. You should also have a look into its implementation so that you can come up with a custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

nodeA.js

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

this.socket = io("urlNodeB:3000");
let data = { something: 'something' }

this.socket.emit('triggerEvent', data, (responseFromB) => {
    // continue with response from B
    console.log(responseFromB)
});
```

nodeB.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on("connection", socket => {

  socket.on('triggerEvent', (data, callback) => {

    // process data from node A
    let dataProcessing = data

    callback(dataProcessing);
  });
}

server.listen(3000, () => console.log('server up'));
```